# List<NameValuePair> Java

Tags: java

Пишу приложение по примеру. В примере используется список для хранения пар значений:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));
```

Android Studio ругается на `NameValuePair`и подсвечивает его.
Как я понял используется библиотека

```
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
```

Которая у меня также подсвечивается `NameValuePair` в конце.
Это получается у меня такой библиотеки нет в проекте? Если да, то как ее добавить?

Comment: Вам действительно нужен `NameValuePair`? Может просто заменить его на `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev не знай, я просто пишу приложение по примеру. В дальнейшем с помощью него отправлют Post-запрос на сервер и получают ответ: JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product, "POST", params);
Если нет разницы, то можно и ваш вариант использовать

Answer (score 2):

Да, надо подключить библиотеку, вот ссылка на последнюю версию https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.5

Там все есть.

Jar - http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.5/httpclient-4.5.5.jar

Maven -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle - `compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.5'`

Comment: я добавил jar файл в папку libs. В build.gradle (Module: app) появилась в dependies строчка: implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.5.5.jar'). Как библиотеку использовать? List все также подчеркнут красным

Comment: @danilshik Если вы используете gradle то лучше не качать jar, а использовать репозитории для этого в build.gradle надо прописать:

`repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.5'
}`

Comment: это в build.gradle (Module: app) нужно вставлять или в (Project:....)

Comment: @danilshik Ах да забыл это же android (я ошибся).
В build.gradle (Module: app) пропишите `android { useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' }` и все.